# Valgrind malloc invalid writes and reads in C

Tags: c, valgrind

I have written the following program in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stack{
    int *arr;
    int top;
};

struct stack* init(int size){
    struct stack *s=NULL;
    s=malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->arr=malloc(sizeof(int) * (size));
    s->top=-1;
    return s;
}

void push(struct stack* t, int val){
    ++(t->top);
    t->arr[t->top]=val;
}

void pop(struct stack* t){
    if(t->top != -1)
        t->top--;
}

int peek(struct stack *t){
    if(t->top != -1)
        return t->arr[t->top];
    return -1;
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *t){
    if(t->top == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int adjVisited(int n, int **g, int i){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(g[i][j] == 1)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void Euler(int v, int n, int **g, int e){
    struct stack *temp=init(e+2);
    struct stack *ans=init(e+2);
    push(temp, v);
    while(!isEmpty(temp)){
        int u=peek(temp);

        if(adjVisited(n, g, u)){
            push(ans, u);
            pop(temp);
        }
        else{
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(g[u][j] == 1){
                    push(temp, j);
                    g[u][j] = 0;
                    g[j][u] = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(temp->arr);
    free(temp);
    while(!isEmpty(ans)){
        printf("%d ", peek(ans));
        pop(ans);
    }
}

void addEdge(int n, int** g, int u, int v){
    g[u][v]=1;
    g[v][u]=1;
}

int main(){
    int n, e, x, y;
    printf("Enter number of nodes in the graph\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int **graph = (int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int *)); 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
         graph[i] = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter number of edges in the graph\n");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    printf("Enter end vertices of the edge to be added\n");
    while(e--){
        scanf("%d %d", &x,&y);
        addEdge(n, graph, x, y);
    }
    
    Euler(0, n, graph, e);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        free(graph[i]);
    free(graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind throws me invalid write and invalid read error. This is the first time that I have come across this error. From what I know about it, it occurs whenever I want to write data to a memory location that has not been dynamically allocated.

```
==4199== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4199== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4199== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4199== Command: ./a.out
==4199== 
Enter number of nodes in the graph
6
Enter number of edges in the graph
6
Enter end vertices of the edge to be added
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 0
==4199== Invalid write of size 4
==4199==    at 0x109294: push (hier.c:31)
==4199==    by 0x109477: Euler (hier.c:75)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199==  Address 0x4a52bc4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4199==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10923E: init (hier.c:24)
==4199==    by 0x1093AA: Euler (hier.c:60)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199== 
==4199== Invalid read of size 4
==4199==    at 0x1092F4: peek (hier.c:41)
==4199==    by 0x1093F2: Euler (hier.c:66)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199==  Address 0x4a52bc4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4199==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10923E: init (hier.c:24)
==4199==    by 0x1093AA: Euler (hier.c:60)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199== 
==4199== Invalid write of size 4
==4199==    at 0x109294: push (hier.c:31)
==4199==    by 0x10941E: Euler (hier.c:69)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199==  Address 0x4a52c64 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4199==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10923E: init (hier.c:24)
==4199==    by 0x1093CC: Euler (hier.c:62)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199== 
==4199== Invalid read of size 4
==4199==    at 0x1092F4: peek (hier.c:41)
==4199==    by 0x10951A: Euler (hier.c:86)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199==  Address 0x4a52c78 is 20 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4199==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4199==    by 0x10923E: init (hier.c:24)
==4199==    by 0x1093CC: Euler (hier.c:62)
==4199==    by 0x1096D4: main (hier.c:114)
==4199==
```

EDIT: I get this error when testing for the following input

```
6 as number of vertices
9 as number of edges
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 0
0 2
2 4
0 4 as the edges of the graph
```

Can anyone help me resolve this error?

Comment: Where are your #includes ?? Yes, they matter.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to make your code snippets as small as possible while still reproducing the error. This is how you should debug in general, and if you still need help those of us on stackoverflow are happy to help if you've made it easier for us to read and understand.  =)

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 0):

You assign the number of edges to variable `e`, in your example `e == 9`.

Then you have a while loop where you decrease `e` while reading in the edges:

```
while (e--)
{ ... }
```

After that `e` will be `-1`.

The you call `Euler` with `e==-1` as an argument. You allocate memory in `arr` for `-1 + 2 == 1` elements, which is not enough for the 9 edges.

Upon the second call to `push` you try to write to element index `1` in `arr` which is not allocated. Thus valgrind reposts that you *write of size 4* to an address which *is 0 bytes after a block of size 4*.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You overflow your stacks. Add some logging to `push` and you will see this happen.